# How do I count the maximum number of two characters in a array?

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a character array consisting of the elements b and r arranged as {'b','b','r','r','b','r'};

What I want to find is the maximum number of those two characters without an interruption in their arrangement.

Example:
ar = {'b','b','r','r','b','r'};

The output should be 4 because bb rr each contains two characters and there is no mixing of b with rr or r with bb.

This is what I came up with :

```
int i =0;
    int max=0;
    while(i<ar.length){
        char c = ar[i];
        int count = 0;
       while(i<ar.length&&ar[i] ==c){i++;count++;}
       if(i==ar.length)break;
       char n_c = ar[i];
       while(i<ar.length && ar[i]==n_c){i++;count++;}
       if(i==ar.length) break;
       if(count>max) max=count;
    }
```

Comment: See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the maximum sub array length which contains only continious `r` and `b`, here is a solution. The basic idea is using two cursor and greedy search.

```
public static int findMaximum(char[] input) {
    int result = 0;
    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
    while (input[first] == input[second]) {
        second++; // the second index should start from another character
    }
    while (second < input.length) {
        int preSecond = second; // copy second, in need reset first to it
        while (second + 1 < input.length && input[second] == input[second + 1]) {
            second++; // increment second
        }
        result = Math.max(result, second - first + 1);
        if (second < input.length - 1) {
            first = preSecond;
        }
        second++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

some test cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(findMaximum(new char[]{'b','b','r'})); //3
    System.out.println(findMaximum(new char[]{'b','b','r','r'})); //4
    System.out.println(findMaximum(new char[]{'b','b','r','r','r','b','r'})); //5
    System.out.println(findMaximum(new char[]{'b','b','b','r','r','b','r'})); //5
    System.out.println(findMaximum(new char[]{'b','b','r','r','b','r','r','r','r','r'})); //6
}
```

Comment: This is helpful!